# How do I upgrade from Pop OS to Ubuntu?

Tags: apt, package-management, 19.10

I installed pop OS and want to upgrade to Ubuntu, but when I do `sudo apt install Ubuntu-desktop` and successfully start Ubuntu, I can't remove `pop-desktop` with aptitude or apt. Can anyone help?

Comment: We mostly don't know the various aspects unique to pop os. "Upgrading" to Ubuntu from what is essentially another distro may or may not be a clean operation. I always prefer to use a clean system of the distro I decide to use. I use VMs (or other partitions) for experimenting and for testing development versions.

Comment: To save you the hassle you probably should perform a clean install, backup your file first.

Comment: I haven't done it and have no special knowledge, but I doubt Pop has any user config differences that will impact Ubuntu, so I'd remove or disable Pop's repositories, then re-install using 'something-else'  (of Ubuntu) and your existing partitions, and I'd opt for no-format of partitions. This is an unclean install, where `ubiquity` (Ubuntu's installer) will note your packages, wipe system directories, install, add back your prior packages (if available) without touching user config/files (unless you said to format). I don't know the effects after Pop; but it would be my likely option.

Comment: @Sambhav Surana Interesting question, can't figure out why anyone would consider it off-topic. There are plenty of questions about upgrading Windows to Ubuntu.

Comment: @C.S.Cameron you mean replacing Windows with Ubuntu?

Comment: @DK Bose I mean that a Ubuntu system is an upgrade to a computer from a Windows system. Upgrade - raise (something) to a higher standard, in particular improve (equipment or machinery) by adding or replacing components.